# Minitest: Testing for Infinity

Tags: ruby, minitest

I am trying to create a Minitest test that tests for an instance of `Infinity` being returned in an array. However I am getting an uninitialized constant error. How do I check for `Infinity` in an array?

This is the test:

```
def test_lgamma
   x = 0
   z = Math.lgamma(x)
   puts z
   assert_equal [Infinity, 1], z
end
```

This is the error:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Tests::Infinity
    .../CORE_MATH.rb:131:in `test_lgamma'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a constant of the `Float` class:

```
assert_equal [Float::INFINITY, 1], z
```

If you're using a version before 1.9.2, try:

```
assert_equal [1.0 / 0, 1], z
```

Comment: How would you do -Infinity?

Comment: @fmorales Put a `-` in front. (Which seems fairly reasonable...)

Comment: I would have thought that too... 
I'm getting an error that says it's almost right, but not quite.

assert_equal [-Float::INFINITY], z
1) Failure:
Tests#test_log [.../CORE_MATH.rb:139]:
Expected: [-Infinity]
  Actual: -Infinity

Comment: I can work around it and call to_s on z and then use assert_equal "-Infinity", z     But that seems kludgey

Comment: @fmorales Because it's expecting an array with -Infinity in it, so you have to wrap the -infinity in an array.